# How do you map subclass properties to columns in Table per Hierarchy?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, abp

I have a TPH situation where I have an abstract base class and 8 derived classes from it by using a discriminator. Two of them share a list of sub classes.

```
 public abstract class StepBase : FullAuditedEntity<Guid>
    {
        public int Order { get; set; }
        public StepType StepType { get; set; }
    }
```

The thing is I have two types which shares a SubClass

```
 public class DestinationVesselStep : StepBase
    {
        public virtual List<DestinationVessel> VesselsDestination { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 public class LiquidNitrogenStep : StepBase
    {
        public virtual List<DestinationVessel> DestinationsBoxes { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    private static void ConfigureVesselsStep(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<DestinationVesselStep>(b =>
        {
            //Properties
            b.HasMany(p => p.VesselsDestination).WithOne().HasForeignKey(x => x.StepId);
        });
    }

    private static void ConfigureLiquidNitrogenStep(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<LiquidNitrogenStep>(b =>
        {
            //Properties
            b.HasMany(p => p.DestinationsBoxes).WithOne().HasForeignKey(x => x.StepId);
        });
    }
```

But when I request a LiquidNitrogenStep with two or more destinationBoxes I get the following error:
System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains more than one element.

it works fine if I only have one destinationBox

I am expecting to get a LiquidNitrogenStep with all its destination boxes, the error do not happnd with DestinationVesselStep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DestinationVessel.StepId can't refer to both a DestinationVesselStep and LiquidNitrogenStep.

So either add separate foreign keys to DestinationVessel, eg LiquidNitrogenStepId, and DestinationVesselStepId, or make the relationships many-to-many, which uses separate linking tables for each relationship, instead of putting foreign keys on the target Entity.

```
private static void ConfigureVesselsStep(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<DestinationVesselStep>(b =>
    {
        //Properties
        b.HasMany(p => p.VesselsDestination).WithMany( d => d.DestinationSteps);
    });
}

private static void ConfigureLiquidNitrogenStep(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<LiquidNitrogenStep>(b =>
    {
        //Properties
        b.HasMany(p => p.DestinationsBoxes).WithMany(d => d.LiquidNitrogenSteps);
    });
}
```